# USB Drivers for Samsung Galaxy Grand Neo Duos GT-I9060I?

Tags: usb-drivers

I can't find the USB drivers for the Samsung Galaxy Grand Neo Duos, GT-I9060I, on the Samsungs Official site or anywhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ADB drivers and see if it works.

The download link is here - http://adbdriver.com/downloads/